# jspdf to addImage : error supplied data is not a JPEG

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64, jpeg, jspdf

I am trying to add an image to my pdf:

```
var image = '../images/example.jpg';
doc.addImage(image, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 700, 145);
```

and I get this error:

> Error: Supplied data is not a JPEG

however, when I add a base64 image:

```
var image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/6GADS...'
doc.addImage(image, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 700, 145);
```

it works fine!

why is the first version not working?
I am trying this:

```
var image = $base64.encode('../images/example.jpg')
```

the same error above again!

what is happening here? what is the solution?

Comment: I have this exact problem, but only on the live version, not on my local version. How is this possible, what is missing? I just updated the file, and now it's not working at all. Is there any other solution than below? I'm reading it similar to above but responsetype as blob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this](https://gist.github.com/HaNdTriX/7704632).

```
function toDataUrl(src, callback, outputFormat) {
  // Create an Image object
  var img = new Image();
  // Add CORS approval to prevent a tainted canvas
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  img.onload = function() {
    // Create an html canvas element
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    // Create a 2d context
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataURL;
    // Resize the canavas to the image dimensions
    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    // Draw the image to a canvas
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    // Convert the canvas to a data url
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    // Return the data url via callback
    callback(dataURL);
    // Mark the canvas to be ready for garbage 
    // collection
    canvas = null;
  };
  // Load the image
  img.src = src;
}
```